# Facebook Graph Api Insights is returning empty data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am using Graph Api Insights for pages but sometimes page_consumptions are returning empty data :/

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=92645906441%2Finsights%3Fpretty%3D0%26since%3D1498374000%26until%3D1498546800%26metric%3Dpage_consumptions&version=v2.9

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=209490822531894%2Finsights%2Fpage_consumptions%3Fsince%3D1498374000%26until%3D1498546800&version=v2.9